# Induction proof

Tags: real-analysis, induction

> Let $0<a_1<b_1$ and define, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, 
>   $$a_{n+1}=(a_nb_n)^{1/2}, \ b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n).$$
>
> by induction show that $a_n<b_n$. Show that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge
>   to the same limit.

How will I be able to prove this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_{n}<b_{n}$, then $a_{n}^{2}-2a_{n}b_{n}+b_{n}^{2}=(a_{n}-b_{n})^{2}>0$ so $4a_{n}b_{n}<(a_{n}+b_{n})^{2}$. Take square roots.

For the second part, check that the $a_{n}$'s increase and the $b_{n}$'s decrease so you have two bounded monotone sequences which then converge. If $a_{n}\rightarrow a$ and $b_{n}\rightarrow b$, then using the relation $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+b_{n})$ and replacing the terms by the respective limits, you get $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First, show that $a_n$ is increasing, $b_n$ is decreasing, and $a_n \lt b_n$  Now each is a bounded monotonic series, so they converge.  Let $A$ be the limit of the $a_n$ and $B$ be the limit of the $b_n$.  Then you must have $A=\sqrt {AB}, B=\frac 12(A+B)$